# Custom Website Design Like Facebook

Tags: legal, copyright, design

Well most of us do like Facebook Design, I' am making Social Networking Website using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). I' am planning to make my own custom website design from scratch using Bootstrap just like Facebook design but the colours coding and few other things will be different. Will their be any problem in regards to violating Facebook Copyright? This is not highlighted in their [Branding](https://www.facebookbrand.com/)

Please note that, I will not be copying any CSS Codes from Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not design it to look and feel just like Facebook if I where you. 
There is always a unclear line when it comes to the copyright. If they feel you violate their copyright they can contact you to make changes and if you don't they can take it to the court.

Try to make something unique that makes it clear that it is not the Facebook design.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lawyer, but there is very little that is unique about Facebook's design, besides the exact color and the Facebook logo. It's just a standard layout that's on many other sites.

Comment: So I guess it wouldn't hurt the copyright.